# Knockout.js Binding to dropdownlist

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to bind data to a dropdown list,

```
    function EmailTemplate(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.etId = ko.observable(data.email_template_id);
        self.etTypeId = ko.observable(data.email_template_type_id);
        self.etTitle = ko.observable(data.email_template_title);
        self.etContent = ko.observable(data.email_template_content);
        self.etAppYear = ko.observable(data.app_year);
        self.etSubject = ko.observable(data.subject);
        self.etActive = ko.observable(data.active);
    }

    function EmailTemplateViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.ETList = ko.observableArray();

        var uri = '/admin/services/EmailTemplateService.svc/EmailTemplates';
        OData.read(uri, function (data, response) {
            $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {
                self.ETList.push(new EmailTemplate(item));
            });
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new EmailTemplateViewModel());            
    });
```

HTML markup:

```
 <select data-bind="options: ETList, value:etId, optionsText: 'etTitle' "class="dropdown"></select>
```

When I run this I got:
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: etIdis not defined;
Bindings value: options: ETList, value:etId, optionsText: 'etTitle'

When we bind to drop down list, how should we bind the value? and after binding, how should we capture or create dropdown change event in Knockout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with `<select>` options, the `value` binding will determine which of the options is selected, usually you'll want an observable in your viewmodel (e.g. `selectedTemplate`) that this is set to. Then this observable will automatically be mapped to the actual object from the observable array. Setting `value: etId` doesn't make sense since there's no `etId` in your root viewmodel.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/968Gy/

```
function EmailTemplateViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ETList = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();
    // ...
}
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: ETList, value:selectedTemplate, optionsText: 'etTitle'" class="dropdown"></select>
```

You might have intended to to `optionsValue: 'etId'` which would work but is usually a less preferable approach (because the observable's value would now be set to the ID instead of the actual object)

Comment: thanks a lot @antishok! etId is not in the root viewmodel, but neither does etTitle. In this case, how should I be able to bind text to etTitle and bind value to etId, so when I change drop down selection, I could get etID instead of etTitle?

Comment: Ok I got it, I could just say selectedTempalte() && selectedTemplate().etId. So selectedTemplate is an object of binded to option, but showing etTitle as text!!

Comment: <span data-bind="text: selectedTemplateType() && selectedTemplateType().etId"></span> still don't know why we need to call selectedTempalte() first and then use &&, what's that for?

Comment: It's needed there because at first there is no item selected, so `selectedTemplate() === undefined`. it's the same as doing: `selectedTemplate() ? selectedTemplate().etId : undefined`. Without this we'd get an error for trying to access `.etId` on undefined

Comment: yes! Thanks a lot for the explanation. I have another question, the dropdownlist actually is a trigger, once selected changed, then subscribe the selectedTemplate to call a ajax to pull data back, for initial load, it's fine,I bind to a observableArray like self.ETList, but how should I clean this observableArray each time dropdown changes selection and pull back data, now it's keep adding, and if I assign self.ETList = []; after ajax callback but before databind, then i don't get anything...

Comment: I got it, use removeall() for the array