# Binding Issue using Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

api using Knockout.js. I want to bind dropdownlist dynamically.Here the code i used for knockout

```
function LeadModel() {

        var that = this;
        that.Saleslist = ko.observableArray("") //Sales list is my model



    }

    function SalesEmpNm() {

        var that = this;
        that.LeadModel = new LeadModel();
        that.reset = function () {

            that.LeadModel.Salesid("");
            that.LeadModel.SalesNme("");
        };
        that.submit = function () {

            var json1 = ko.toJSON(that.LeadModel);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/values',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: json1,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    var message = data.Message;
                }
            });
        };
    };
    var _vm = new SalesEmpNm();
    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(_vm);
    });
```

Here my text

Sales Name:

```
<select id="ddlSales" name="ddlSales" 
        data-bind="options:$root.LeadModel.Saleslist, Value:'Salesid', 
          Text:'SalesNme', Value:LeadModel.Salesid">
            </select>
```

Pleas suggest me the answer for binding dropdownlist dynamically.
Thanks & Regards

Comment: refer the link
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825539/knockout-js-binding-to-dropdownlist

Comment: can you show how you are populating dynamic values in your observable array??

Comment: from value controller I am passing the values using return value and this is binding the values through script which I have posted.Please suggest me to resolve this issue

Comment: Here my api controller 
 foreach (var lst in obj)
            {
                select.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = lst.Sales_Person_Id.ToString(), Text = lst.Sales_Person_Name });
            }
            leadmdl.Saleslist = select; //Saleslist is my list which contains Text and Value of my dropdownlist

Answer (score 2):

i can't see where you are populating your Saleslist array.
However, following should work in your case:

```
<select id="ddlSales" name="ddlSales"
data-bind='optionsCaption: "[Please Select]", options: _vm.LeadModel.Saleslist(), optionsText: "SalesNme", optionsValue: "Salesid"'></select>
```

Note that I am binding the array like `_vm.LeadModel.Saleslist()`

another issue in your models is `LeadModel` does not have `Salesid` and `SalesNme` attributes which you are accessing in `reset` function:

```
that.reset = function () {
    that.LeadModel.Salesid("");
    that.LeadModel.SalesNme("");
};
```

Comment: In Value controller iam getting the Saleslist array but unfortunately
not working in my case.

Comment: i am having those attributes in my leadmodel class . everything looks perfect but data not binding ? any script  issues ?? i am confused

Comment: seems to be script issue. check browser console for any.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be you're initializing your `ko.observableArray("")` with an empty string `""`, which isn't supported.  You might just need to change it to `ko.observableArray()`.

But as @Ahsan said, there might be other issues in your pasted code, such as the undefined `Salesid` and `SalesNme`, and your `success` handler doesn't populate the `Saleslist` as I would've expected.

Comment: Yes your right iam not getting the data in script can you please suggest me where might be wrong in my script but in api controller im getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is because you aren't providing any values in your `Saleslist`.

This would solve that issue:

```
this.Saleslist = ko.observableArray([
    { Salesid: 1, SalesNme: "One" },
    { Salesid: 2, SalesNme: "Two" }
});
```

Comment: Its fine with static value but dynamic value is not coming.